# CUPS Raspberry Pi print server, stops responding after a few print jobs

Tags: archlinux, printing, cups

I am using my Raspberry Pi for a number of different tasks, one of which is a print server using CUPS.  I am running Arch Linux as an OS.

Using pacman, I got down the latest version of CUPS (Windows and Linux network printer) and also Avahi-Daemon which I configured so that my Apple devices can find my printer as an AirPrinter on the local network.  The printer itself is a Samsung ML-1630 which the manufacturer does not provide an ARM based printer driver for so I am using [Splix](http://splix.ap2c.org/) which appears to work rather well.  I have both of these services enabled on startup so they will start immediately after booting up my Pi.

It will print a test page out and I have successfully tested printing a document from Microsoft Word on my Windows machine, OpenOffice Writer from my Ubuntu machine, and Notes from my iPad.  It appears that after a few minutes or so of the service running that there is some strange connection problem when printing from any device.  I recently sent three different print jobs from my Ubuntu machine, multiple copies of each.  It printed the first job correctly, then half way through the second job Ubuntu notified of a connection problem.  I tried printing a test page from the Windows machine at this point and nothing came of it.

The strange part is that if I was still able to access the CUPS dashboard through my browser.  According to the CUPS dashboard the printer was Idle with an empty queue and waiting for requests.  When I `shutdown -r now` the backed up print jobs will start processing again on the client machine but again, it will print 6 or 7 pages then it stops responding again.

Because it sits there most often doing nothing I also have it run a dynamic IP address update client for a DNS (remote SSH) and in its spare processing power I have it mining Litecoins (it is a reprehensibly poor miner).  Is it possible that these other daemons I have running would cause such printing problems?

Any other ideas about what might be happening here?  IPTables is running but I am allowing all traffic on 631, apparently as I am able to access the CUPS dashboard no problem.

Comment: If your Pi is overclocked then try it at normal speed.

Comment: @avra Thanks for responding.  I was overclocking with overvoltage at one point but only for a brief moment because I was curious just how high of a hashrate I could achieve with CPU mining on Litecoin.  I thought I set it back though because I didn't want to damage the unit by leaving it run like that for long periods of time.  Perhaps I forgot to scale it back or perhaps I just scaled back over voltage?  I will double check and get back to you

Comment: I've got the same problem, after 7 or 8 pages the printer seems to be waiting and stops printing.
With 6 pages max per job it works.
I am running under raspbian with cups 1.5.3.
Did you find a solution or maybe where was the problem ?